# Optimization for mongoDB comparison query in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to compare a log entry against a collection in mongo containing ip address ranges and assign details to it, such as country/city/location etc
I am getting an very slow processing speed, so I'm thinking maybe there would be a better way to go about this?

```
var logEntry = new LogEntry
{
    Ip = ip,
    // more fields here
    UserAgent = userAgent.Equals("-") ? null : userAgent,
    IpLocation = IsIpInRangeAsync(ip)
};
logs.Add(logEntry);

private static Ip IsIpInRangeAsync(string ipAddress)
{
    IPAddress targetIp = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);
    byte[] ipBytes = targetIp.GetAddressBytes();
    uint ipValue = BitConverter.ToUInt32(ipBytes.Reverse().ToArray(), 0);

    var filter = Builders<Ip>.Filter.And(
        Builders<Ip>.Filter.Lte("StartIp", ipValue),
        Builders<Ip>.Filter.Gte("EndIp", ipValue)
    );

    Ip detailsFound = _ip.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault();
    return detailsFound;
}
```

Comment: You might consider indexing. This will cost more memory.

Comment: Thanks, I have already added indexes for both the columns but still it is rather slow in performance

Comment: simplify your question, as I can see, the question has nothing about IP address handling and logs. Leave only information directly relocated to your technical question

Comment: Did you add a composite index for `{ StartIp: 1, EndIp: 1}`? I don't think there is anything more you could do. What do you consider as "slow in performance"?

Comment: Yes actually I did! Well it takes ~1 sec to parse each log entry which I think is kind of too much. I found another workaround, I assign locations to the ips as soon as they are uploaded so that I only need to do a simple GET afterwards and everything is included